# Nginx proxy_cache caches 502 errors

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm using Nginx proxy_cache to cache responses from a Node server. When that server is offline Nginx returns a custom 502 page. All going well so far...

When the Node server comes back online Nginx keeps returning the 502 page for 5 mins (my cache time). If I delete all the files in the cache dir it makes no difference. If I restart Nginx it busts the cache and starts serving real content again.

Is it normal for Nginx to cache 502s? Note that it's not caching a 502 response from the backend server it's caching the fact that the server isn't accessible.

What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to figure this out myself. Nginx really does cache the knowledge that the upstream server is inaccessible.

To fix this I changed my cache config from `proxy_cache_valid any 5m;` to `proxy_cache_valid 5m;` Removing `any` implies you only want to cache 200, 301, and 302 responses.

Comment: The same applies to all ``*_cache_valid`` directives, including ``uwsgi_cache_valid`` for ``uwsgi_cache``, and ``fastcgi_cache_valid`` for ``fastcgi_cache``.  Just clarifying this somewhat already-obvious point for ease of discovery via web searches.

Comment: Thanks davidjb. I find it obvious that any response would be cached but surprising that a lack of response would be cached. Also, all the advice I've seen on clearing the nginx cache suggests you can just delete all the cache files. That doesn't work for this case.